# jquery IF not do something ELSE do nothing - not working

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I realize there are many similar questions but I am implementing the answers and yet I still cannot get it to work.  I have some jquery that changes an image when hovering over a list item.  Got it working great but with the fade effect, it seems to fade out and in even when the correct image is already there.  I figured if I add an `if` statement and leave out the `else`, it would only perform the function if the image path was not equal and do nothing if it is equal.
I have a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MilkyTech/m89tybcf/36/). No syntax errors.  Looks like it should work but no.

jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var path = 'https://avayoupaint.com/images/';
  $('.menu-child').mouseenter(function() {
    var newimage = $(this).attr('data-path') + '.jpg';    
    if(newimage != (path + $('.swap > img').attr('src'))) {
        $('.swap > img').fadeOut(100,function() {
        $(this).attr('src', path + newimage).fadeIn(100)
      });
    } 
  })
});
```

html:

```
<section class="submenuWrapper">
    <ul class="twinsub">
        <li class="twinmultisub twinleft">
             <ul>
                  <li class="menu-child" data-path="menu-interior"><a href="#"><span>Interior Painting</span></a></li>
                  <li class="menu-child" data-path="menu-exterior"><a href="#"><span>Exterior Painting</span></a></li>
             </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="twinmultisub twinimg">
             <section class="swap">
                 <img src="https://avayoupaint.com/images/menu-exterior.jpg" />
             </section>
        </li>   
    </ul>
</section>
```

Comment: In what way **exactly** does it not work? Does *anything* happen? What debugging have you done so far?

Comment: when you hover over a list item and the correct image for that list item is already there, it appears as if it is "reloading" the same image rather than doing nothing.  It behaves exactly how it did before I added the `if` statement.

Comment: Logic is flawed. You are comparing the file name `newimage` to the full url of existing image. Some simple logging or breakpoints would help you debug this

Comment: try using $(this).data("path") to pull your data from your element.  And what the other guy said about the filename vs full url.

Comment: Well have you tried logging the value of `newImage` and the value of that expression you're comparing it to?

Comment: @Pointy I don't know how to do that.  I'm somewhat new to javascript, hence me posting for help here.

Comment: `console.log(newImage)` etc

Comment: after you create newImage, console.log(newImage), then console.log($('.swap > img').attr('src')),  you can view in the console (chrome developer tools) and determine why your conditional is not evaluating as expected.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console

Comment: thanks for this tool!  I've been using DevTools for many years and didn't know how to use the console.  figured out my issue with the path.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you were adding the path to the wrong side of your comparison. You want to compare:

```
path + newimage !== $('.swap > img').attr('src')`
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var path = 'https://avayoupaint.com/images/';
  $('.menu-child').mouseenter(function() {
    var newimage = $(this).attr('data-path') + '.jpg';

    if(path + newimage !== $('.swap > img').attr('src')) {
        $('.swap > img').fadeOut(100,function() {
        $(this).attr('src', path + newimage).fadeIn(100)
      });
    } 
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="submenuWrapper">
    <ul class="twinsub">
        <li class="twinmultisub twinleft">
             <ul>
                  <li class="menu-child" data-path="menu-interior"><a href="#"><span>Interior Painting</span></a></li>
                  <li class="menu-child" data-path="menu-exterior"><a href="#"><span>Exterior Painting</span></a></li>
             </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="twinmultisub twinimg">
             <section class="swap">
                 <img src="https://avayoupaint.com/images/menu-exterior.jpg" />
             </section>
        </li>   
    </ul>
</section>
```

Comment: yep, I already figured it out using the `console.log()` recommended above.  I should have deleted the question.